# Using object tag with parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JS to run the following code:

```
document.write("<OBJECT classid='xxx' NAME = 'abc' codebase='/abc.exe'>")
document.write("<PARAM NAME='serverip' VALUE='" + SERVER_IP + "'>") 
document.write("</OBJECT>")
```

The file is on the server and the code manages to run the program on the client side.

My problem is that the app reads its arguments and the first one it reads is the server ip. In the above code, the app runs without any parameters to it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.write("<OBJECT classid='xxx' NAME = 'abc' codebase='/abc.exe'>" +
               "<PARAM NAME='serverip' VALUE='" + SERVER_IP + "'>" +
               "</OBJECT>");
```

Comment: Maybe explain the *why* as well? Or at least link to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! though it didn't work